# how to export to excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, dataset

I am using Crystal Reports and I have a lot of bugs. Firstly, an ugly bug which I solved that was to do with user and password. I'm not using username/password for my database (in Access)

I don't know why it failed, but my other option is passed the information to Excel using C#. I am going to have the name in a textbox.

```
"information enters-left of angel rodrigo"

"here's a datagrid"

date        enter    left    timepassed
28/06/2011   8:00    9:00       1:0
29/06/2011   7:55    8:00       0:55
```

I want to pass this information from his name up until the datagrid, and pass all this to Excel. 
My database is going to continue being in Access, I want to pass to Excel for printing.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you could export it as a csv, excel can open csvs and parse them.